# Count identical dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe with a date column and I would like to create a new column that tells me how many identical dates the dataset contains. This is a min example of the original data set:

df1:

```
date         
2017/01/03     
2017/01/03     
2017/01/04     
2017/01/04     
2017/01/04     
2017/01/05
```

I would like to create this date_count, so the target data set is:

df1:

```
date         date_count
2017/01/03     2
2017/01/03     2
2017/01/04     3
2017/01/04     3
2017/01/04     3
2017/01/05     1
```

The actual code to create df1:

```
dict1 = [{'date': '2017/01/03', 'date_count': 2},{'date': '2017/01/03',              'date_count': 2}, 
 {'date': '2017/01/04', 'date_count': 3},{'date': '2017/01/04',   'date_count': 3},
{'date': '2017/01/04', 'date_count': 3},{'date': '2017/01/05',    'date_count': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['s1', 's2','s3','s1','s2','s3'])
```

Comment: Do you know about `groupby`?

Comment: I do now. But that would only give me an output which lists the occurences, right?

Comment: `df.groupby('date').count()`

Comment: you can just use a `groupby` and the `pd.merge` or `transform`.

Comment: @user3483203 he wants to merge back on the original df

Comment: Then `transform('count')`

Comment: @ As I suggested. but he should tell us which one is his original df.

Comment: I have added  the original df and the target df above

Answer (score 6):

Here is another method using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) along with a [`groupby` and `size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
>>> df
          date
s1  2017/01/03
s2  2017/01/03
s3  2017/01/04
s1  2017/01/04
s2  2017/01/04
s3  2017/01/05

df['date_count'] = df.date.map(df.groupby('date').size())

>>> df
          date  date_count
s1  2017/01/03           2
s2  2017/01/03           2
s3  2017/01/04           3
s1  2017/01/04           3
s2  2017/01/04           3
s3  2017/01/05           1
```

Comment: this works perfectly!!! thanks

Comment: Is this significantly faster or slower than just transform? It's certainly safer than `transform('size')` in the case of sending it an empty DataFrame, but `.transform('count')` doesn't seem to suffer from that.

Comment: It looks faster to me `523 µs ± 17.4 µs` vs `1.88 ms ± 39.4 µs`.It will be interesting to see how it works for bigger df.

Comment: On small dataframes, map will be faster, this will not be the case on very large dataframes.  Probably will switch around 50k rows.  `transform` will become faster earlier based on the change I just made

Comment: @user3483203 That's exactly what I found

Answer (score 3):

Using **`count`** with **`transform`**

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('date')['date'].transform('count')

         date  count
0  2017/01/03      2
1  2017/01/03      2
2  2017/01/04      3
3  2017/01/04      3
4  2017/01/04      3
5  2017/01/05      1
```

Comment: I'm wondering why is not working without `.reset_index()`.

Comment: Because there is only a single column, so once you groupby it has nothing to count, `reset_index` gives it a column to aggregate

Comment: Thanks. I never used `df` with one column only.

Comment: @user32185 I didn't realize you could index the column you grouped by, which significantly speeds up this method.